# akka - get list of ActorRef from ActorSelection

Tags: scala, akka

`ActorSelection` support [wildcard](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.1/general/addressing.html#Querying_the_Logical_Actor_Hierarchy)  and it allows to send a message to all actors that match the selection:

```
context.actorSelection("../*") ! msg
```

Is there a way to retrieve the list of `ActorRef` that match the selection from the `ActorSelection`?
From the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4.2/?_ga=1.259422220.765823280.1452780169#akka.actor.ActorSelection) I can see that there is a `resolveOne` function but not (for example) a `resolveList`.

**Update**

The reason why I want the list of `ActorRef` is that I would like to use the `ask` operator on all the actors that match the selection.

Just to be clear here is an example of what I would like to do:

```
object MyActor {
  case object AskAllActors
  case object GetActorInfo
}

class MyActor extends Actor {
  import MyActor._

  def receive = {
    case AskAllActors =>
      val actors: List[ActorRef] = context.actorSelection("../*").resolveList()
      val result: List[Future[String]] = actors.map { a => (a ? GetActorInfo).mapTo[String] }
      Future.sequence(result).map { result =>
        // do something with result: List[String]
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The ability to get a list of the form

```
val timeout : FiniteDuration = 10 seconds

val actorList = actorSelection.resolveMany(timeout)
```

does not exist.  I suspect the reason is because once the timeout expires there is a chance that an Iterable, of non-zero length, is returned but it would be impossible to know if the Iterable is comprehensive.  Some Actors may not have had enough time to respond.  With `resolveOne` the issue does not exist, the first responding ActorRef is the result.

Based on the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.2/scala/actors.html#actorselection-scala) it looks like you could use the `Identify` message to have all of the `Actors` specified in an `actorSelection` respond with identification:

```
class Follower extends Actor {
  val identifyId = 1
  context.actorSelection("../*") ! Identify(identifyId)

  def receive = {
    case ActorIdentity(`identifyId`, Some(ref)) => ...
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution and certainly works. But it doesn't solve my original issue. Actually my question is too generic. I'll update it to be more specific.

Comment: @tano I updated my answer in accordance with your update.